# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, exception

hey I have a problem with  loading data from a txt file

```
private void read() {


          try {
                // open the file for reading
                InputStream instream = openFileInput(File.separator + "bla.txt");


            // if file the available for reading
            if (instream.available() >0) {
              // prepare the file for reading
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

              String line;

              // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
              while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                  for(int i= 0; i<=1; i++){
                        if(i == 0){
                            bla = Integer.parseInt(buffreader.readLine());
                        }
                        if(i == 1){
                            bla2 = Integer.parseInt(buffreader.readLine());
                        }


                  }

            // close the file again      
            instream.close();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Ladevorgang war efolgreich!",

                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }}
          }

               catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Datei nicht vorhanden",

                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
         catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please help me I dont know what I should change:(
I alway got the android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 
Thanks for help Strik3r

```
private  void save() {

    try {

        File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "bla.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(string.toString() + "\n");
        myOutWriter.append(string2.toString());

        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Gespeichert",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this is the save data

Comment: Where is the file saved?

Comment: the file saved already work

Comment: post the entire logcat then

Comment: problem is not with the code you have shown, `ResourceNotFoundException` is usually happens when you try to use a resource which is not in android resources folder.

Comment: 06-10 06:14:25.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1830): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
06-10 06:14:25.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1830):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
06-10 06:14:25.028: E/AndroidRuntime(1830):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)

Comment: @Nisha I added the save data and the logcat:)

Comment: Try : ` InputStream instream = openFileInput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "bla.txt");` in the first line of your `read()` method.

Comment: Your current problem is with `Resources$NotFoundException`, coused by setting text of a `TextView` to not existing resource. Not with  the reading `bla.txt` file. So first fix the resource problem.

Comment: hmm okay thanks...but what Is the resource problem in tihs application?:o

Comment: Post the entire code. It looks like you are trying to read an editText which is not probably defined in the xml.

Comment: as @mike_m pointed out, the code throwing exception is not available. So please post the entire code.

Comment: and how can i read the file if the write is in another activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // open the file for reading

    InputStream instream = openFileInput(File.separator + "bla.txt");
```

does not seem to be a valid file. 
Instead, please try

```
InputStream instream = openFileInput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator + "bla.txt");
```